# Recreating iTunes library from a .itdb file?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

My laptop has recently died, taking with it iTunes and my music.  Things could have been a lot worse, but I fortunately have a back up of my mp3s.  However, I have lost the iTunes library containing all my play counts, last played, ratings etc.

I am keen to recover this data and have bought software to access my iPod Touch as a hard drive which has enabled me to view the underlying files.  However I don't seem to be able to find a version of the **iTunes Library.itl** (or iTunes Music Library.xml) file which would contain the meta data I need.

The only seemingly useful file I can find is the **library.itdb** file, which seems about the right file size to contain the data I'm looking for.

My question therefore is can anyone advise if there is a way of recreating the library .itl or .xml file from this .itdb (iTunes database) file?

All advice gratefully received!

---

NB. I have managed to extract the meta data I need but the program I am using creates its own *path* to the the mp3 file, which would leave every track broken.